# Find specific text in .log date

Tags: powershell

I have per example 5 .log files a.log , b.log , c.log , d.log , e.log with dates 10.09.2021 ; 11.09.2021 ; 12.09.2021 ; 13.09.2021 ; 14.09.2021.

How can I find specific text in all files between date 11.09.2021 - 13.09.2021 and print in console all line where find string ?

```
$startdate = Read-Host -Prompt "Please type StartDate:"
$enddate = Read-Host -Prompt "Please type EndDate:"

@(Get-Content -recurse -from $startdate > $enddate | Where-Object {$_contains("test" "test2")}).Count
```

Return:

Found in file b.log , c.log from $startdate > $enddate string 'test' 'test2' >>> 3 err
asdmsd**test**iasdiwix91281...
128amsd**test2**o128jajdj2...
91mawuuw**test**912mkaksdwa...

Thank you.

Comment: Please give us examples of such log files. Now we don't even know where in each line to look for a date in that format..

Comment: Hi, doesn't matter in logs. logs create every day at 00:00 night. I want to make a script for read in folder where is logs every logs between 2 dates.

#1. Open Script
#2. Enter start date (last modify date) eg. 10.09.2021
#3. Enter end date (last modify date) eg. 15.09.2021
#4. Go in C:\test\logs
#5. Search in every logs with date (last modify date) 10.09.2021 - 15.09.2021 (there is 5 logs for every day)
#6. Return results : Found 5 err in logs (10.09 - 15.09) and show all line where script find err.

ad**test**las >> in log 11.09
jasid**test2** iwa >> in log 14.09